# Изменение стиля кнопок "Закрыть", "Свернуть" и т.д. в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5

Все знают такой инструмент, как VS Code. Мне очень нравятся кнопки закрытия и сворачивания окна:

[image: Кнопки управления окном в VS Code]

Как реализовать такое же, используя PyQt5 для разработки графического интерфейса?

Comment: Изменить стиль кнопок? Qt Style Sheet. Или вручную сделать кнопку, но это может оказаться несколько сложнее QSS

Comment: @gil9red Чтобы получить возможность применения таблиц стилей, мне нужен объект кнопки. Как получить к нему доступ? В QMainWindow есть какой-то атрибут "CloseButton"?

Comment: А никак -- только вручную создавая заголовок окна + рамку, т.к. их рисует система, а точнее оконный менеджер

Comment: @gil9red В PyQt5 это можно как-то сделать, используя инструменты этой библиотеки? Или взаимодействовать с системой напрямую нужно?

Comment: Через Qt, у меня есть пример этого, покажу в ответе

Comment: @gil9red Заранее благодарю. Вы часто меня выручали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Пример создания окна с кастомным заголовком окна](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/49e1c18aae309da18604f1c9c2c4ca22e1588487/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt__custom_title_bar__FramelessWindow/FramelessWindow.py):

```
from enum import Enum, auto


from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QEnterEvent, QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QPushButton


# стиль
STYLE_SHEET = """
/* Панель заголовка */
TitleBar {
    background-color: rgb(54, 157, 180);
}
/* Минимизировать кнопку `Максимальное выключение` Общий фон по умолчанию */
#buttonMinimum, #buttonMaximum, #buttonClose {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(54, 157, 180);
}
/* Зависание */
#buttonMinimum:hover,#buttonMaximum:hover {
    background-color: rgb(48, 141, 162);
}
#buttonClose:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(232, 17, 35);
}
/* Мышь удерживать */
#buttonMinimum:pressed,#buttonMaximum:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(44, 125, 144);
}
#buttonClose:pressed {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(161, 73, 92);
}
"""


class TitleBar(QWidget):
    # Сигнал минимизации окна
    windowMinimumed = pyqtSignal()

    # увеличить максимальный сигнал окна
    windowMaximumed = pyqtSignal()

    # сигнал восстановления окна
    windowNormaled = pyqtSignal()

    # сигнал закрытия окна
    windowClosed = pyqtSignal()

    # Окно мобильных
    windowMoved = pyqtSignal(QPoint)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Поддержка настройки фона qss
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self._old_pos = None

        # Размер значка по умолчанию
        self.iconSize = 20

        # Установите цвет фона по умолчанию, иначе он будет прозрачным из-за влияния родительского окна
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(palette.Window, QColor(240, 240, 240))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        # значок окна
        self.iconLabel = QLabel()
        # self.iconLabel.setScaledContents(True)

        # название окна
        self.titleLabel = QLabel()
        self.titleLabel.setMargin(2)

        # Использовать шрифты Webdings для отображения значков
        font = self.font() or QFont()
        font.setFamily('Webdings')

        self.buttonMinimum = QPushButton('0', clicked=self.windowMinimumed.emit, font=font, objectName='buttonMinimum')
        self.buttonMaximum = QPushButton('1', clicked=self.showMaximized, font=font, objectName='buttonMaximum')
        self.buttonClose = QPushButton('r', clicked=self.windowClosed.emit, font=font, objectName='buttonClose')

        # макет
        layout = QHBoxLayout(spacing=0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        layout.addWidget(self.iconLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.titleLabel)

        # Средний телескопический бар
        layout.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))

        self.layout_custom_widget = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_custom_widget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        layout.addLayout(self.layout_custom_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMinimum)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMaximum)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonClose)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        # начальная высота
        self.setHeight()

    def addWidget(self, widget, width=38, height=38):
        self.layout_custom_widget.addWidget(widget)

        widget.setMinimumSize(width, height)
        widget.setMaximumSize(width, height)

    def showMaximized(self):
        if self.buttonMaximum.text() == '1':
            # Максимизировать
            self.buttonMaximum.setText('2')
            self.windowMaximumed.emit()
        else:  # Восстановить
            self.buttonMaximum.setText('1')
            self.windowNormaled.emit()

    def setHeight(self, height=38):
        """ Установка высоты строки заголовка """
        self.setMinimumHeight(height)
        self.setMaximumHeight(height)
        # Задайте размер правой кнопки  ?
        self.buttonMinimum.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMinimum.setMaximumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMaximum.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMaximum.setMaximumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonClose.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonClose.setMaximumSize(height, height)

    def setTitle(self, title):
        """ Установить заголовок """
        self.titleLabel.setText(title)

    def setIcon(self, icon):
        """ настройки значокa """
        self.iconLabel.setPixmap(icon.pixmap(self.iconSize, self.iconSize))

    def setIconSize(self, size):
        """ Установить размер значка """
        self.iconSize = size

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)
        self.showMaximized()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие клика мыши """
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = event.pos()
        event.accept()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие отказов мыши """
        self._old_pos = None
        event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self._old_pos:
            self.windowMoved.emit(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos() - self._old_pos))
        event.accept()


# Перечислить верхнюю левую, нижнюю правую и четыре неподвижные точки
class Direction(Enum):
    LEFT = auto()
    TOP = auto()
    RIGHT = auto()
    BOTTOM = auto()

    LEFT_TOP = auto()
    RIGHT_TOP = auto()
    LEFT_BOTTOM = auto()
    RIGHT_BOTTOM = auto()


class FramelessWindow(QWidget):
    # Четыре периметра
    MARGINS = 7

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET)

        self._old_pos = None
        self._direction = None

        self._widget = None

        # Фон прозрачный
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        # Нет границы
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # TODO: AttributeError: 'FramelessWindow' object has no attribute 'setWindowFlag'
        # self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # Отслеживание мыши
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        # макет
        layout = QVBoxLayout(spacing=0)

        # Зарезервировать границы для изменения размера окна без полей
        layout.setContentsMargins(self.MARGINS, self.MARGINS, self.MARGINS, self.MARGINS)

        # Панель заголовка
        self.titleBar = TitleBar(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.titleBar)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        # слот сигнала
        self.titleBar.windowMinimumed.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.titleBar.windowMaximumed.connect(self.showMaximized)
        self.titleBar.windowNormaled.connect(self.showNormal)
        self.titleBar.windowClosed.connect(self.close)
        self.titleBar.windowMoved.connect(self.move)
        self.windowTitleChanged.connect(self.titleBar.setTitle)
        self.windowIconChanged.connect(self.titleBar.setIcon)

    def setTitleBarHeight(self, height=38):
        """ Установка высоты строки заголовка """
        self.titleBar.setHeight(height)

    def setIconSize(self, size):
        """ Установка размера значка """
        self.titleBar.setIconSize(size)

    def setWidget(self, widget):
        """ Настройте свои собственные элементы управления """

        self._widget = widget

        # Установите цвет фона по умолчанию, иначе он будет прозрачным из-за влияния родительского окна
        self._widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = self._widget.palette()
        palette.setColor(palette.Window, QColor(240, 240, 240))
        self._widget.setPalette(palette)
        self._widget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self._widget)

    def move(self, pos):
        if self.windowState() == Qt.WindowMaximized or self.windowState() == Qt.WindowFullScreen:
            # Максимизировать или полноэкранный режим не допускается
            return

        super().move(pos)

    def showMaximized(self):
        """ Чтобы максимизировать, удалите верхнюю, нижнюю, левую и правую границы.
            Если вы не удалите его, в пограничной области будут пробелы. """
        super().showMaximized()

        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

    def showNormal(self):
        """ Восстановить, сохранить верхнюю и нижнюю левую и правую границы,
            иначе нет границы, которую нельзя отрегулировать """
        super().showNormal()

        self.layout().setContentsMargins(self.MARGINS, self.MARGINS, self.MARGINS, self.MARGINS)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        """ Фильтр событий, используемый для решения мыши в других элементах
            управления и восстановления стандартного стиля мыши """
        if isinstance(event, QEnterEvent):
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        """ Поскольку это полностью прозрачное фоновое окно, жесткая для поиска
            граница с прозрачностью 1 рисуется в событии перерисовывания, чтобы отрегулировать размер окна. """
        super().paintEvent(event)

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 255, 255, 1), 2 * self.MARGINS))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие клика мыши """
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие отказов мыши """
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

        self._old_pos = None
        self._direction = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие перемещения мыши """
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

        pos = event.pos()
        xPos, yPos = pos.x(), pos.y()
        wm, hm = self.width() - self.MARGINS, self.height() - self.MARGINS

        if self.isMaximized() or self.isFullScreen():
            self._direction = None
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            return

        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self._old_pos:
            self._resizeWidget(pos)
            return

        if xPos <= self.MARGINS and yPos <= self.MARGINS:
            # Верхний левый угол
            self._direction = Direction.LEFT_TOP
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

        elif wm <= xPos <= self.width() and hm <= yPos <= self.height():
            # Нижний правый угол
            self._direction = Direction.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

        elif wm <= xPos and yPos <= self.MARGINS:
            # верхний правый угол
            self._direction = Direction.RIGHT_TOP
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)

        elif xPos <= self.MARGINS and hm <= yPos:
            # Нижний левый угол
            self._direction = Direction.LEFT_BOTTOM
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)

        elif 0 <= xPos <= self.MARGINS and self.MARGINS <= yPos <= hm:
            # Влево
            self._direction = Direction.LEFT
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeHorCursor)

        elif wm <= xPos <= self.width() and self.MARGINS <= yPos <= hm:
            # Право
            self._direction = Direction.RIGHT
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeHorCursor)

        elif self.MARGINS <= xPos <= wm and 0 <= yPos <= self.MARGINS:
            # выше
            self._direction = Direction.TOP
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeVerCursor)

        elif self.MARGINS <= xPos <= wm and hm <= yPos <= self.height():
            # ниже
            self._direction = Direction.BOTTOM
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeVerCursor)

        else:
            # Курсор по умолчанию
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)

    def _resizeWidget(self, pos):
        """ Отрегулируйте размер окна """
        if self._direction is None:
            return

        mpos = pos - self._old_pos
        xPos, yPos = mpos.x(), mpos.y()
        geometry = self.geometry()
        x, y, w, h = geometry.x(), geometry.y(), geometry.width(), geometry.height()

        if self._direction == Direction.LEFT_TOP:          # Верхний левый угол
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos

            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos

        elif self._direction == Direction.RIGHT_BOTTOM:    # Нижний правый угол
            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._old_pos = pos

            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._old_pos = pos

        elif self._direction == Direction.RIGHT_TOP:       # верхний правый угол
            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos

            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._old_pos.setX(pos.x())

        elif self._direction == Direction.LEFT_BOTTOM:     # Нижний левый угол
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos

            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._old_pos.setY(pos.y())

        elif self._direction == Direction.LEFT:            # Влево
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos
            else:
                return

        elif self._direction == Direction.RIGHT:           # Право
            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._old_pos = pos
            else:
                return

        elif self._direction == Direction.TOP:             # выше
            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos
            else:
                return

        elif self._direction == Direction.BOTTOM:          # ниже
            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._old_pos = pos
            else:
                return

        self.setGeometry(x, y, w, h)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = FramelessWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('Test')

    # Добавить свое окно
    w.setWidget(QTextEdit("Hello World!", w))
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

Код не мой, а находил его [здесь](https://github.com/892768447/PyQt/blob/f6ff3ee8bf8e7e9dd8d3ba3d39cf5cefa3c91e7b/%E6%97%A0%E8%BE%B9%E6%A1%86%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E6%A0%87%E9%A2%98%E6%A0%8F%E7%AA%97%E5%8F%A3/FramelessWindow.py).

Главная фишка в `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` эта настройка говорит оконному менеджеру, что не нужно рисовать его рамку, из-за чего возможно создать собственные заголовки.

**PPS.**

Тот виджет поддерживает добавление других виджетов в заголовок:

```
class MainWindow(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, frameless_window):
        super().__init__()

        # Использовать шрифты Webdings для отображения значков
        font = self.font()
        font.setFamily('Webdings')

        self.buttonMy = Qt.QPushButton('@', clicked=self._on_process_clicked, font=font)
        self.buttonMy.setStyleSheet("""
* {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(54, 157, 180);
}
*:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: green;   /* rgb(232, 17, 35) */
}
        """)

        self.line_edit_my = Qt.QLineEdit('Test!', returnPressed=self._on_process_clicked)

        self.titleBar = frameless_window.titleBar
        self.titleBar.addWidget(self.line_edit_my, width=75, height=20)
        self.titleBar.addWidget(self.buttonMy)

        self.textEdit = Qt.QTextEdit()

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.addWidget(Qt.QCommandLinkButton('Click!', clicked=lambda: self.textEdit.append('>>> ')))
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _on_process_clicked(self):
        self.textEdit.append("Нажата `Своя Кнопка` -> '{}'!".format(self.line_edit_my.text()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = FramelessWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('Тестовая строка заголовка')
    w.setWindowIcon(Qt.QIcon('icon.ico'))

    # Добавить свое окно
    w.setWidget(MainWindow(w))
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Для этого у виджета нужно вызвать `.titleBar.addWidget`, пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]